# swagger server php

Tags: php, swagger

[image]

use the swagger-ui,But I don't know how to build server in php .and Why the Response body does not reponse the "sd" and "s" ,How to use the swagger-ui with the php?I am try hard,does any body to help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at restler https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/tree/v3

Alternatively you can construct the swagger docs manually, like here:

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/no-server